# Difference between concatenating the id and html tag i.e. ul#nav vs #nav ul

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I was just playing around with a css ul for a menu. My initial css of

```
#nav ul {...}
```

did not work, but

```
ul#nav {...}
```

worked. What's the reason for this?

Another similar question is what is the difference between:

```
div.grey
```

OR

```
div .grey
```

Notice the space between the two...

Comment: +1 Welcome to Stack Overflow, Ken Ma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`#nav ul` looks for an `ul` element within an element having the id of "nav".

```
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>Like me</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

`ul#nav` looks for a `ul` that has the id value of "nav".

```
<ul id="nav">
  <li>Like me</li>
</ul>
```

The same goes for classnames:

`div.grey` looks for a `div` element having the classname "grey".

```
<div class="grey">Foo</div>
```

Whereas `div .grey` looks for any element having the classname "gey" within a `div`.

```
<div>
  <p class="grey">
    I'm special!
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#nav ul {...}
```

selects ul elements inside an element with id nav

```
ul#nav {...}
```

select a ul element with id nav

> When you are using an id selector no
>   need to use a tag selector.

```
div.grey
```

select a div element with class name grey

```
div .grey
```

selects all elements with class name grey inside all div elements

For detailed reading see **[Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors)**

Answer (score 0):

...

```
#nav ul {...} means ul inside an element having id nav

ul#nav means ul element having id nav
```

Same is the case with classes example you have shown.

**[See CSS Selectors at W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html)**